# как заустить Qtdesigner

Tags: python, qt-designer

[image: сам архив]как из этого архива запустить QtDesigner

Comment: Вы пакет установили или у вас только архив?

Answer (score 1):

Вынести например ярлык с путем типа.

```
C:\Users\XNeo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin\designer.exe
```

Только вам надо не из архива запускать, а сперва установить пакет через pip например.

Вот [тут](https://python-scripts.com/pyqt5) все подробно описано.